# Difference between two selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, selector

In jQuery there is a selector called `first-child`. It selects the first child
from the matched element. But instead of `first-child` if I use `first-of-type`, it also works just fine. So I am just wondering, what is the difference?

```
$(function(){
   //$('li :first-child').text('some text');
   $('li :first-of-type').text('some text');
});
```

Comment: You really should have just read the documentation.

Comment: ok. i read the documentation but not got the clear picture. so i just post here. now i got some example, so my doubt is clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read the docs ([`:first-of-type`](http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) and [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)):

> **`:first-child`**
>   Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.
>
> **`:first-of-type`**
>   Selects all elements that are the first among siblings of the same element name.

The `:first-of-type` selector will match the first element of a given name (e.g. `span`, `a` etc) amongst a set of siblings. Your example will match:

```
<li>
    <span>Matches this span</span>    <!-- First span amongst siblings -->
    <a>Matches this a</span>          <!-- First a amongst siblings -->
    <a>Doesn't match this one</span>  <!-- Second a amongst siblings -->
</li>
```

The `:first-child` selector will simply the match the first child of a parent:

```
<li>
    <span>Matches this span</span>    <!-- First child of parent -->
    <a>Doesn't match this</span>      <!-- Second child of parent -->
    <a>Nor this</span>                <!-- Third child of parent -->
</li>
```